# Is there a way to force HttpClient to open a new TCP connection for a request?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular / typescript and I'm using HttpClient to 'Get' a resource on our application.

Since our customer has a WAF proxy (F5/Incapsula etc.) in which there's a rule that ignores an HTTP request using an existing TCP connection, I need to make sure my flow opens a new TCP connection.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

I've searched google & StackOverflow and unfortunately couldn't find an answer.

I can see that the API provides methods of adding/removing headers but since I can't rely on the fact that it's HTTP 1.0 removing the 'keep alive' header won't help.

I know that HTTP 1.1 and 2 are attempting to multiplex and keep as many TCP connections opened for as long as they can.

I've tracked the tcp connections with 'TcpView' and saw through chrome developer tools that when the my HTTP request starts if there are tcp connections opened to that remote address I don't see a new TCP connection but if enough time passed and there are no TCP connections opened my HTTP request opens a new one.

I want that to happen even if there are opened TCP connections.

Comment: angular (and any other web client framework for that matter) can only use the APIs provided by the browser. that is `XHR` and `fetch`. there will never be low level access to TCP.

Comment: Thank you,
In that case I guess I'll handle it 'businessly' and take it up with the P.M/P.O.